# split list based on common element?

Tags: python

I have a large list of tuples containing data;

```
test = [
    ('admin', 1, 2),
    ('admin', 3, 4),
    ('admin', 5, 6),
    ('user', 1, 2),
    ('user', 3, 4),
    ('user', 5, 6),
    ('guest', 1, 2),
    ('guest', 3, 4),
    ('guest', 5, 6)
   ]
```

How can I split these up into 3 separate iterables based on element0 of the tuple? e.g.;

```
[('**admin**', 1, 2),('admin', 3, 4),('admin', 5, 6)]

[('**user**', 1, 2),('user', 3, 4),('user', 5, 6),]

[('**guest**', 1, 2),('guest', 3, 4),('guest', 5, 6)]
```

Thanks in advance!
Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
iterables = {}
for x in test:
    iterables.setdefault(x[0], []).append(x)
```

Then your iterables are `iterables.values()`.

Comment: simple and effective! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

```
from collections import defaultdict

buckets = defaultdict(list)
for tup in test:
    buckets[tup[0]].append(tup)
```

Comment: To get the answer in the format you desire, just use buckets.values()

Comment: The only issue I can think of here is that the order of appearance isn't preserved.  That could be rectified by using `OrderedDict`/`setdefault`, but I don't need that very often so I seldom bother.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with list comprehension:

```
>>> test = [('admin', 1, 2), ('admin', 3, 4), ('admin', 5, 6), ('user', 1, 2), ('user', 3, 4), ('user', 5, 6), ('guest', 1, 2), ('guest', 3, 4), ('guest', 5, 6)]
>>>
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> 
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(test, key=itemgetter(0)), itemgetter(0))]
[[('admin', 1, 2), ('admin', 3, 4), ('admin', 5, 6)], [('user', 1, 2), ('user', 3, 4), ('user', 5, 6)], [('guest', 1, 2), ('guest', 3, 4), ('guest', 5, 6)]]
```

Comment: This asserts that the input list is sorted by the first tuple element already (which is true for the example given by the OP, but may not always be the case). You can also shorten your loop to just `[list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(test, elem0)]` (`elem0` being just `operator.itemgetter(0)`).

Comment: Nice.  Only drawback I see is if `things` is not sorted.  You may want to put `sorted(things)` in your call to `groupby`.  Also, why not `newlist.append(list(group))`?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yeah, changed the code. Thanks :)

Comment: For that matter, why not `[list(group) for key, group in groupby(test, lambda x: x[0])]`?

Comment: Again, I'm not sure that the tuples coming in sorted order is invariant.  If it isn't, do `groupby(sorted(things), ...)`.

Comment: Minor: `sorted(test, operator.itemgetter(0))` won't work, you need to give it `key=oper..`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski you're correct, the list must be sorted by first element for groupby to work as desired.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski DSM Thanks for your inputs. Modified the code. Now it would work for unsorted list too. :)